# Scala equivalent of Ruby's map.each?

Tags: scala

Very handy Ruby code:

```
some_map.each do |key,value|
  # do something with key or value
end
```

Scala equivalent:

```
someMap.foreach( entry => {
  val (key,value) = entry
  // do something with key or value
})
```

Having to add the extra `val` line bugs me.  I couldn't figure out how to state the function arg to extract the tuple, so I'm wondering is there a way to do this, or why is there no foreach that extracts the key and value for me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works, too:

```
someMap.foreach {case (key, value) =>
  // do something with key and/or value
}
```

Comment: A case statement is really a partial function in disguise is why this handy decomposition shorthand works.  That might help someone who is mystified by the type error that results from mismatching this sort of expression.

Comment: Good article on partial functions here http://ebruchez.blogspot.com/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html

Answer (score 11):

I like this one:

```
scala> val foo = Map( 1 -> "goo", 2 -> "boo" )
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> goo, 2 -> boo)

scala> for ((k,v) <- foo) println(k + " " + v)
1 goo
2 boo
```

Comment: There's no need for `val` inside the `for` generator.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need even the `val` in for loop:

Following ViktorKlang's example:

```
scala> val foo = Map( 1 -> "goo", 2 -> "boo" )
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> goo, 2 -> boo)

scala> for ((k, v) <- foo) println(k + " " + v)
1 goo
2 boo
```

Note that `for` is rather powerful in Scala, so you can also use it for [sequence comprehensions](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111):

```
scala> val bar = for (val (k, v) <- foo) yield k
bar: Iterable[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
```

Comment: `for` is actually a Monad Comprehension disguised as a `for` loop, so as to not scare away the Java programmers with concepts such as *Monad*. (Just like query comprehensions in C#/VB.NET are just monad comprehensions disguised as SQL queries.) So, it's even more powerful than sequence comprehensions.

Comment: Jörg, don't use the M word, it scares people ;-)

Comment: @ViktorKlang: Exactly! That's why Martin Odersky disguised them as something Java programmers already know: a `for` loop. And Erik Meijer disguised them as a SQL query in C# and VB.NET, Don Syme disguised them as a Unix shell pipeline in F#, Simon Peyton Jones disguised them as a C block in Haskell. (Sometimes I think they would be *less* scary if they weren't constantly hiding in the shadows ...)

Answer (score 2):

Function.tupled converts a function `(a1, a2) => b)` to a function `((a1, a2)) => b`.

```
import Function._
someMap foreach tupled((key, value) => printf("%s ==> %s\n", key, value))
```